# How can I know if a BufferedReader is chained with a DataInputStream?

Tags: java, file, java-7

In a method I need a BufferedReader wrapping a DataInputStream as a parameter. I want to declare the method as this :

```
public void firstPass(BufferedReader inStream){ // some code ... }
```

But I don't know how I can check whether inStream is wrapping a DataInputStream.

I've tried

```
public static void firstPass(BufferedReader inStream){
    if (inStream instanceof DataInputStream){

    }       
}
```

but the code can't compile (Eclispe does not accept the code : "Incompatible conditional operand types BufferedReader and DataInputStream").

---

Why this need ? Because I want to use with the same variable inStream :

- the method readLine() from BufferedReader
- the method readDouble() from DataInputStream

So I need a stream which chains both classes.

I'm programming with Java 7 JDK.

Could someone help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the whole point of the decorator pattern is that you don't care about what implementation of `InputStream` is passed. Why do you need to check this?

Comment: @TudorThanks for your answer, please check the edited question.

Comment: Hmmm... but if you only get a `BufferedReader` how can you use the `readDouble` of the underlying `DataInputStream`?

Comment: That's the problem I'm facing : in fact I read a file of values written as text file, but now I understand that my processing method is not good => Use it as a text stream, split "words" and parse each with the correct wrappers.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us how you plan to use this `BufferedReader` we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: In fact i want to read an obj file (the original code was from a C project, that I want to adapt to Java) : so that there it is a text file such as 'f 1/2/3 \n f 10 30 40' (for recall). I have many numerical values to process inside a text file. But the values are 90% of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataInputStream can never be a instance of BufferedReader - they are both in separate class hierarchies.

A BufferedReader wraps another Reader, not a Stream.

You can bridge from Streams to Readers using an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Reading doubles and lines from the same Reader doesn't really makes sense - one is raw binary data, the other is character data. Maybe you need to read a textual encoding of the doubles, and parse this using `Double.parseDouble(text)`.

Comment: The was not the question I'm afraid. He was asking how to check if the wrapped input stream is a `DataInputStream`.

Comment: His question doesn't make sense, because there _is_ no wrapped InputStream, because a BufferedReader _does not_ wrap Streams.

Comment: It wraps a `Reader` that can wrap an `InputStream`.

Comment: @DNA I agree with you : I should process only as a text file, and then parse with the good numerical wrappers. Thanks a lot : I've understood I made an illogical process :)

Comment: @Laurent BERNABE use a Scanner for that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Thank you, I've forgotten about this Scanner class :)

Answer (score 1):

A. It is not possible to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish with maybe adding a flag to your method that is accepting the bufferedReader argument

B. It's not clear how you are passing the DataInputStream to a BufferedReader (probably through InputStreamReader right?) But in any case it seems wrong that you are using BufferedReader and DataInputStream together. BufferedReader is going to use your DataInputStream like a plain InputStream, so I don't know why you would have put the DataInputStream around it

Comment: Yes, I use InputStreamReader, like this : try (BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(name)))))) {

Comment: What is the DataInputStream doing there? What would happen if you dropped it? ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I lost the DataInputStream because the BufferedReader was on top of the stream chain, and that I passed this BufferedReader to the method.

Comment: You can get it back using reflection but what you get back will be in an unknown state i.e. you can't use it to read data if that's what you are trying to do. As I keep saying, you can't safely mix BufferedReader and DataInputStream on the same stream.

Comment: Yes, I'll follow your advise : see my comment to one of your response above.

Answer (score 1):

**DataInputStream** class isn't subtype of class **BufferedReader**

```
class DataInputStream extends FilterInputStream implements DataInput {}

class BufferedReader extends Reader {}
```

**More info:**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` is not a sub class of `DataInputStream` so your error is logical...

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReaders are for text data and DataInputStream is for binary data. You would never wrap one with the other unless you like confusing people.

You can use a DataInputStream to wrap a BufferedInputStream (It wouldn't make any sense to wrap it the other way)

You can wrap a BufferedReader around an InputStreamReader, but there is no simple way to determine this has been done.

You could write

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
```

But you would have to use **the reflections library** to determine what the BufferedReader wraps.

Comment: But through chained constructors you can wrap a `DataInputStream` inside a `BufferedReader`. He is asking how to check whether the wrapped input stream is indeed a `DataInputStream`.

Comment: You can do a lot of things which don't make sense and this is one of them. Perhaps he is looking for bugs in his code, but this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm agree with you. If i come to such a buggy process, it's because i though bad my solution to the main problem => Reading an OBJ file. I need to process in a different way, and leaving out the DataInputStream.

Comment: If the OBJ file is text, try the example I gave you above.